# How to convert a string into function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I converted a function into string using stringify and stored into database. 
But how to add this string as function to a variable

lets assume i get string like i am showing in A

```
var A = "function aF() {\n    console.log(\'change1\');\n}"
```

I want to add aF function to a object key like this

```
{handle: A }
```

But i am getting this in result

```
{ handle: 'function aF() {\n    console.log(\'change1\');\n }' }
```

instead i want this

```
{handle:[function: aF]} or {handle:[function]}
```

Because variable A is typeof string. Is there any way to convert A into function and then store into handle key.

Comment: You can use eval, to convert string to function like eval('function asd(){}')

Comment: You can also use [the Function() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

Comment: Can you use JSON.stringify? Then you can use JSON.parse.

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek JSON does not handle functions

Comment: Can't use JSON on executable code.

Comment: You have to go back several years to find browsers that don't support JSON.  Additionally, the use of eval() was always discouraged.

Comment: It is best to rethink what it is you are trying to do such that there is no need to store code as a string.

Comment: @ScottMarcus i have to store as per my requirement.

Comment: Unless you're 100% sure that the source (the database) is absolutely safe you can use eval, but I'm personally really discouraging it. Either find an alternative or just switch the entire logic of the current system. To be entirely honest, there should almost never be any need to evalize a string from a database. Can you please briefly explain us why you need to do so?

Comment: I don't know why people giving negative point to question. People should come with solution, not with excuse don't do and all.

Comment: @briosheje i can't explain why i need this but i have to store function as string in database. so later i can use it.

Comment: @ScottMarcus https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Comment: @briosheje yes i am aware of this. but if the project you going to do is for your personal purpose. database is 100% safe and only personal developer will use this thing thats why i am not thinking about security and wanna do this.

Comment: You guys have expressed your concerns about using `eval()` if you really want to keep talking about it take it to chat please. Also the user said that he is not worried about the security issue so there is no need to keep repeating yourselves over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres how I would do it, this is pretty much another take on other responses but doesnt involve any sub-strings. The comments on the code pretty much say it all.

```
var yourExample = createFunction("function aF() {\n    console.log(\'change1\');\n}");
yourExample(); // prints change1 in console

var fnWithParam = createFunction("function aF(param1) { console.log(param1); }");
fnWithParam(2); // prints 2 in console


// creates a function from a string, that string must be a function itself.
function createFunction(fnStr) {
    // make a function which returns a function, unwrap that function by calling it with apply();
    return new Function('return ' + fnStr).apply();
}
```

Also to help reduce your exposure to access to objects such as `window` or `document` you can create new variables inside the function scope which creates that function. For instance:

```
// creates a function from a string, that string must be a function itself.
function createFunction(fnStr) {
    // make a function which returns a function, unwrap that function by calling it with apply();
    return new Function('"use strict"; var window,document; return ' + fnStr).apply();
}
```

Now this doesnt solve all the security issues around creating javascript from strings but I think its better than nothing.

Good readings:

["use strict"; - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

[new Function() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Function constructor to make a functions.

For Example.

```
var A = "function aF() {\n    console.log(\'change1\');\n}" ;
var functionStr = A.substring(A.indexOf("{")+1, A.lastIndexOf("}"));
new Function(functionStr)();
```

**Note:**

Using a string to create `function` object with this method is as risky as `eval()`. You should not do it unless you are sure that user-input is not involved. If user-input is used in making a `function` string then function is not considered secure as user can potentially manipulate around the authentication and authorization since system cannot control (validate) the same.

> what if function aF have some parameter

You need to store the reference to the function object and invoke the same with parameter, for example

```
var A = "function aF() {\n    console.log(\'change1\');\n}" ;
var functionStr = A.substring(A.indexOf("{")+1, A.lastIndexOf("}"));
var functionObj = new Function(functionStr);
```

Now invoke this function with parameter, for example

```
functionObj ( args );
```

or use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
functionObj.call( this, args );//this is the context you want to bind to this funciton.
```

or use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
functionObj.apply( this, args );//this is the context you want to bind to this funciton.
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus: While that's all true, if you **have** to do what the OP describes (turn a string containing the function into an actual function), you're going to have to do this (or `eval`, or creating a script tag, or similar -- which have the same issues). The question's flaws aren't the answer's fault. :-)

Comment: @gurvinder372 what if function aF have some parameter.

Comment: @Rishi : Here is an example with eval + parameter https://jsfiddle.net/1z1sjh5n/ . I'm not sure how to accomplish that using the new Function prototype to be entirely honest, it looks like the closest to your solution is using this. (Also, please, next time clarify in your question that you are aware of eval problems and so on ;) )

Answer (score 0):

An other solution would be to do :

```
var  A = "function aF() {\n    console.log(\'change1\');\n}" ;
eval(A);
{handle:aF}
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day.

I wrote small function.
It is very simple, without many validations.
See here

```
function makeFooFromString(str){
    var m = str.match(/function\s+([^(]+?)\s*\(([^)]*)\)\s*{(.*)}/);
    // function name
    var fooname = m[1];

    // function params
    var params  = m[2];

    // function body
    var body    = m[3];

    // processing params
    if(params.length){
        params = params.split(',');
        for(var i = 0; i < params.length; i++){
            params[i] = params[i].replace(/\s*/, '');
        }
    }else{
        params = [];
    }

    params = params.join(',');

    // make our temp function body
    var text = '';
    text += 'var foo = function('+params+'){'+body+'};';
    text += 'return foo.apply(foo, arguments);';    
    return new Function(text);
};
```

Now i make call like this

```
var foo = makeFooFromString('function get_sum(a, b){ return a+b;}')
```

And test

```
console.log(foo);
console.log(foo(1, 2));
console.log(foo(3, 4));
```

See it on jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/j586xajq/